# Is there a survey on the effect of smoking mariujana to human health?

Tags: lasting-effects-duration, smoking, risks, irreversible-damage, marijuana

There is a wide belief that **smoking** mariujana cures some mental and physical diseases, and actually has no harm to your health.

A large portion of these people are those who really trust scientific studies. But unfortunately, there are a lot of bogus news about science. Most of them advise "do not drink alcohol, instead smoke mariujana."

I have found [this](http://medicalmarijuana.procon.org/view.resource.php?resourceID=000884) website which collected 60 peer-reviewed studies on **medical** mariujana.
However, I could not find any similar collection for smoking mariujana.

I believe smoking *anything* is worse than *any* kind of alcohol since
(i) alcohol harms only after a long time of regular consumption whereas it takes only one pack of smoking *something* to be addicted, and
(ii) the lungs cannot fully clean themselves but only the bad effects, whereas liver can refresh itself, and the body unless it is permenantly damaged.

Is there a survey/study about this matter?